# Nodejs Mongodb second sort() for first sort() results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

format want to appear -

```
msg - 9
...
msg - 17
msg - 18
msg - 19
```

From this function

```
mongo.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
   var collection = db.collection('chat')
   var stream = collection.find().sort({ _id : -1 }).limit(10).stream();
   stream.on('data', function (chatt) {clients[socket.id].emit('chat message', chatt.content); });     

});});
```

But this sorting only give me -

```
msg - 19
msg - 18
msg - 17
...
msg - 9
```

Because it is a chat app and latest rows needed to be at bottom for chat format.
And I tried to add new sorting code to result (I am new to node) - and it resorts the whole db again and give earliest 10 rows.

```
mongo.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
   var collection = db.collection('chat')
   var stream = collection.find().sort({ _id : -1 }).limit(10);
   stream=stream.sort({ _id : 1 }).stream();
   stream.on('data', function (chatt) {clients[socket.id].emit('chat message', chatt.content); });     

});});
```

How can I reverse the result from sort|limit ? Thank you so much.

Comment: `.sort({ _id: 1 })`. Means "ascending" as opposed to "descending" which you have done with `-1`. When in doubt, [look at the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/). That is what it is there for.

Comment: @NeilLunn , Yes you are right, but i want to get is latest 10 rows of ascending order.

Comment: Oh okay. Then it would be better off to sort "descending" but instead of a "stream" use `.toArray()` to get a regular array and then send the sorted array back as one result to your chat client instead. Much more simple and not wasting network overhead.

Comment: Do you always need the latest 10 rows for every message or one initial fetch of the latest 10 rows and then a stream of the rest in real-time?

Comment: @toszter, yes, initial fetch of the latest 10 for real time chat.

Comment: @NeilLunn, as you said, it is more simple and working better. Thank you. it is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this.  *FAIR WARNING: I didn't test this on an ACTUAL MongoDB Connection.* But, this should get the principals across. May the force be with you on your journey with Node!

**Using just an array:**

```
mongo.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection('chat');

  // Get the previous 10 initially.
  var prev10 = collection.find().sort({ _id : -1 }).limit(10).toArray();
  // flush it
  let msg = null;
  while (msg = prev10.pop()) {
    // Remove the last element, which is the first message sent, altering the array in place.
    // Send it to the socket
    client[socket.id].emit('chat_message', msg.content);
  }
});
```

**Using an array for the initial 10, then stream:** *THIS IS A LITTLE KLUDGEY because we're attempting to skip what the initial array fetch returned. I'd rather not do this, but hey why not give it a shot?*

```
mongo.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection('chat');

  // Get the previous 10 initially.
  var prev10 = collection.find().sort({ _id : -1 }).limit(10).toArray();

  // flush it
  let msg = null;
  let count = 0;
  while (msg = prev10.pop()) {
    // Remove the last element, which is the first message sent, altering the array in place.
    // Send it to the socket
    client[socket.id].emit('chat_message', msg.content);
    // Increment
    count ++;
  }

   // Set up your stream, skipping the message already retrieved
   stream=collection.find({}).sort({ _id : -1 }).skip(count).stream();

   stream.on('data', function (chatt) {
      // Stream each incoming message individually.
      clients[socket.id].emit('chat message', chatt.content);
   });
});
```

**PREFERRED, if you JUST want to use streams and not bother with the initial query:** *Here, you can return 10, 20, 100 recent historic messages and it will always adjust to your needs.* The delay always ensures there aren't new records to gather before returning in order of appearance, FILO (First-In, Last-Out). MongoDB is essentially making your FIFO a FILO because of the structure of it's results sort. So you're transforming the order by popping the array it returns.

```
mongo.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection('chat');
  let HISTORYCOUNT = 10;
  let DATADELAY = 10;
  let filoQue = [];
  let delayedFlush = null;
  // Set up the stream.
  var stream = collection.find().sort({ _id : -1 }).limit(HISTORYCOUNT).stream();
  // Read data.
  stream.on('data', function (chatt) {
    // New data show up quickly, so it won't flush...
    if (delayedFlush) { clearTimeout(delayedflush); }
    // ...but rather fill the FILO queue.
    filoQue.push(chatt);
    delayedFlush = setTimeout(function() {
      // Empty the first 10 in your preferred order 9 -> 19
      if (filoQue.length > 0) {
      let msg = null;
      while (msg = filoQue.pop();) {
        // Always remove the last element, which will be the first message sent, altering the array in place.
        // Send it to the socket
        client[socket.id].emit('chat_message', msg.content);
      }, DATADELAY);
   });
});
```

Again, fair warning that I didn't test this on an ACTUAL MongoDB connection. Just tested to make sure the queueing would work for your intents. Let me know if there are bugs and I can edit to help the next.

Comment: Yes, your array solution can solve this problem. Thank you so much for code and references. But I want to warn to other viewers not to use direct connection to mongo db for each connection just like my problem. It caused my CPU up to 100% on much traffic. I solved that problem by mongoose express rest.But I am just a new to node, so It can be wrong for this suggestion.

Comment: You're right to use REST and arrays. The stream is a hog, indeed.